# Putting checkbox and text value into database

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

So I'm using html, php and phpmyadmin.

What I have in HTML is multiple checkbox + a text field.

What I want to is whichever checkbox is selected and whatever the text the user enters, it will get saved into the database so they can retrieve it whenever to edit and delete it.

This is my HTML code snippet of my checkbox and text field
(if you need more code let me know, I will add it but there isn't much other code)

```
    <div class="add"> <label for:="txtAddress">Grocery List for:</label>
        <input type="text" name="txtAddress" size="50">
    </div>
    <label><input type="checkbox" /> Beans </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" /> Banana</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" /> Apples</label>
```

When the user will click submit, it will add that list to the database in phpmyadmin which I already have and made.

I want to know how would I go about this. Any general ideas or suggestion would be appreciated. I think I might need to use PHP but how would I get it to submit to my database

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to submit checkbox values with PHP post method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309801/how-to-submit-checkbox-values-with-php-post-method)

Comment: I'm asking how to submit a checklist to a database

Comment: name your checkboxes as indexes of array:

<input type="checkbox" name="checklist[beans]" value="Beans"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="checklist[banana]" value="Banana"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="checklist[apples]" value="Apples"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert checkbox values in database using following way.

```
<html>  
<body>  
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
<div style="width:200px;border-radius:6px;margin:0px auto">  
<table border="1">  
<tr>  
  <td colspan="2">Select Fruit:</td>  
</tr>  
<tr>  
   <td>Beans</td>  
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="LisCh[]" value="Beans"></td>  
 </tr>  
 <tr>  
  <td>Banana</td>  
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="LisCh[]" value="Banana"></td>  
 </tr>  
 <tr>  
  <td>Apple</td>  
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="LisCh[]" value="Apple"></td>  
 </tr>  

 <tr>  
  <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="submit" name="sub"></td>  
 </tr>  
 </table>  
 </div>  
</form>  

 <?php  
    if(isset($_POST['sub']))  
    {  
      $host="localhost";//host name  
      $username="root"; //database username  
      $word="";//database word  
      $db_name="sub_db";//database name  
      $tbl_name="list"; //table name  
      $con=mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$word","$db_name")or die("cannot connect");//connection string  
      $checkbox1=$_POST['LisCh'];  
      $chk="";  
      foreach($checkbox1 as $chk1)  
      {  
         $chk .= $chk1.",";  
       }  
      $in_ch=mysqli_query($con,"insert into list(checked) values ('$chk')");  
       if($in_ch==1)  
      {  
         echo'<script>alert("Inserted Successfully")</script>';  
       }  
    else  
   {  
      echo'<script>alert("Failed To Insert")</script>';  
   }  
  }  
 ?>  
  </body>  
  </html>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: 120, when I load your html code, the website shows the table and under it shows "alert("Inserted Successfully")'; } else { echo''; } } ?>" I think there might be an error in your code.

Comment: I click submit and it says insert fail

Answer (score 1):

Set name and value in the check box and then create 3 columns for check box like beans,banana,apples.

```
<div class="add"> <label for:="txtAddress">Grocery List for:</label>
        <input type="text" name="txtAddress" size="50">
    </div>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="Beans" value="1"> Beans </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="Banana" value="1"> Banana</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="Apples" value="1"> Apples</label>
```

Then get the request data beans, banana and apples data into that db columns.
For retrieve if the column contain data 1 means it was checked, otherwise not.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever user submit value in textbox and any checkbox is selected, please make array or something if you want to store them in a single field. Btw, you are not making checkbox as array, please fix this.

Once you have array of checkbox and string from textbox, you can manipulate it in any way you want.