# I have a form in which customer can select multiple locations as well as trades and after submission of form I want to filter data

Tags: php, sql, string

I have a form in which customer can select multiple locations as well as trades and after submission of form I want to filter the data from database but I don't understand how to convert these arrays values into string and store in single variable

**This is My form which is Dynamic in nature**

```
<form method="POST" action="">
            <p id="success_para" ></p>
                <div class="navbar-default sidebar hemnav" role="navigation">

                    <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">

                      <h5> Agent By Trades </h5>

                        <ul class="nav in" id="side-menu">

                        <?php
                        $sql_trades=exeQuery("SELECT * FROM `service` WHERE 1");
                        while($res_trades=fetchAssoc($sql_trades)){
                        ?>
                            <li style="padding: 10px;"><input type="checkbox" name="sel_trades[]" value="<?php echo $res_trades['service_id'] ?>" class="filters"> <?php echo $res_trades['service_title'] ?></li>
                        <?php } ?>
                          </ul>
                    </div>

                </div>




<div class="navbar-default sidebar cattwo" role="navigation">

    <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">

      <h5> Agent By Location </h5>

        <ul class="nav in" id="side-menu">

                        <?php
                        $sql_loc=exeQuery("SELECT * FROM `location` WHERE 1");
                        while($res_loc=fetchAssoc($sql_loc))
                        {
                        ?>
                          <li style="padding: 10px;"><input type="checkbox" name="sel_loc[]" value="<?php echo $res_trades['location_id'] ?>" class="filters"> <?php echo $res_loc['location_name'] ?></li>
                        <?php } ?> 

          </ul>

    </div>

</div>

<button type="submit" name="filter" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-blu">Filter Now</button> </button><br><br>

</form>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to submit checkbox values with PHP post method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309801/how-to-submit-checkbox-values-with-php-post-method)

Comment: This is not exactly what I'm looking for thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to get an array in the $_POST for both keys, '[x, y, z]'. What do you want to convert this into? A string?

Any criteria to go with that? If not, `implode(', ', $array)` will turn it into a single string with a comma-separated list. From there, you can store it as a value in a field with proper sanitization.

Comment: Thanks for reply Malovich Actually I'm new in PHP so Don't have exact idea how to to convert arrays of array in a a string

Comment: Here I have 2 things one is location and other is trades so want to make seperate strings for both location and array and would like to store in variable

Comment: Then the code snippet should work. `implode` is a php function that collapses an array down to a string with the first argument being the delimiter, the second being the array to be collapsed, and the function returns the newly created string.

Answer (score 0):

you can use php implode function to store array of selected values

$selection - implode(',',$_POST['sel_loc'])

and then you can store this values in database,

Comment: you can use it twice lol :) one for location and second for trade

Comment: Vote up please then