# PHP picks random value from checkbox

Tags: php, html, sql, forms, post

I'm having a very random problem with my PHP script. I'm displaying a few checkboxes to turn on and turn off my lights with the Raspberry Pi. I'm not new to PHP but i'm new with using checkboxes and setting the value's of it.

The problem is that when i select the checkbox the PHP script **selects random value one of the checkboxes and not the one i selected.**

My code is currently without SQL protection, i have to find the problem first..

***Head of my code:***

```
 <?php
     if(isset($_POST['lamp'])){
        $lamp = $_POST['lamp'];
        echo $lamp;
        $statusSQL = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM lamps WHERE name='$lamp' LIMIT 1");
        $statusFetch = mysqli_fetch_array($statusSQL);
        $lampStatus = $statusFetch['status'];
        $lampID = $statusFetch['id'];
        if ($lampStatus){
            $sql = "UPDATE lamps SET status='0' WHERE id='$lampID'";
            if ($connect->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                echo "Lamp is off";
            }
        }
        else{
            $sql = "UPDATE lamps SET status='1' WHERE id='$lampID'";
            if ($connect->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                echo "Lamp is on";
            }
        }
     }
?>
```

***Getting checkboxes***

```
    <form id="checkForm" method="post" action="dashboard.php">
     <?php  
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM lamps";
        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                echo "<div class='row'>";
                if ($row["status"]){
                    ?>
                    <div class='col-xs-4'><label class='switch'>
                        <input id="lamp" name="lamp" value="<?php echo $row["name"]; ?>" onclick="document.getElementById('checkForm').submit()" type='checkbox' checked>
                        <span class='slider round'></span>
                        </label></div><br>
                        <?
                }
                else{
                    ?>
                    <div class='col-xs-4'><label class='switch'>
                        <input id="lamp" name="lamp" value="<?php echo $row["name"]; ?>" onclick="document.getElementById('checkForm').submit()" type='checkbox'>
                        <span class='slider round'></span>
                        </label></div><br><?
                }
                echo "</div>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "No lamp active in database";
        }
    ?>
   </form>
```

Comment: In your second block of code, the HTML in the `if else` section is not inside an `echo` statement and you end the php code prior to it. What about encasing all of that inside a php tag and using `echo`?

Comment: Richard, all your inputs have the same name and same id. Try making each id and name of the form **unique** and see what happens.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the response. Correct Chris, but it displays it fine. Its just easier for me to make the javascript correct (To call the form). Rafeal i tried to make the ID unique and this didn't work out. When i change the name im unable to call the PHP part.

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309801/how-to-submit-checkbox-values-with-php-post-method